# How to change rootcontainer div id element for a vue3 project created using Quasar

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I created a Vue3 project using Quasar and have a requirement that I have to house this app on a html page along with another Vue app which is sitting on there. Both of the apps are for different functionalities and I cannot club them both.

Now in order to make both the apps work on the same page, I decided to change the root container element of the vue3 app created using quasar and I need some help there. I'm sure I have to play with the boot files but haven't been successful yet. But when I search for "q-app" in all the files, I found some references of that id element (q-app) from the quasar files in node_modules as well and that tricked me. Am not sure if I'm heading the correct direction or just shooting in the dark. Can I be please given some pointers on how to change the root container element id for a Vue3 project created using quasar cli with vite. Or, just replacing the q-app id in the build files is the only option I got? Appreciate your help and thank you for educating me.

added the below line to axios.ts boot file as that is already being referenced from quasar.config.js. Will create a new boot file if I make it work as I learnt that we should have a boot file for each concern.

app.mount('#q-my-test-id')